# Calculating the right number of bits in a bloom filter

Tags: math, bloom-filter

I'm trying to make a configurable bloom filter. In the constructor you set the predicted necessary capacity of the filter (`n`), the desired error rate (`p`), and a list of hash functions (of size `k`).

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter#Probability_of_false_positives), the following relation holds (`m` being the number of bits):

```
p = (1 - k * n / m) ** k
```

Since I get `p`, `n` and `k` as parameters, I need to solve for `m`; I get the following:

```
m = k * n / (1 - p ** (1 / k))
```

However, there are a few things that make me think I did something wrong. For starters, `p ** (1 / k)` will tend towards `1` for a large enough `k`, which means the whole fraction is ill defined (because you can conceivably divide by `0`).

Another thing you may notice is that as `p` (the allowed maximum error rate) grows, so does `m`, which is totally backwards.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Your algebraic manipulation looks correct, but are you sure you're *starting* with a correct formula? The wikipeda page has something *similar to*, but not exactly the same, as what you have...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did solve the equation correctly, however note that Wikipedia states:

```
The probability of all of them being 1, which would cause
the algorithm to erroneously claim that the element is in
the set, is often given as:

p ~= (1 - (1 - 1 / m) ** (k * n)) ** k ~= (1 - Exp(-k * n / m)) ** k
```

This is very different from what you've stated:

```
p = (1 - k * n / m) ** k
```

So what you really want to start with is

```
p = (1 - (1 - 1 / m) ** (k * n)) ** k
```

I worked this out to be

```
(1 - 1 / m) ** (k * n) = 1 - p ** (1 / k)
1 - 1 / m = (1 - p ** (1 / k)) ** (1 / (k * n))
m - 1 = m * (1 - p ** (1 / k)) ** (1 / (k * n))
m - m * (1 - p ** (1 / k)) ** (1 / (k * n)) = 1
m * (1 - (1 - p ** (1 / k)) ** (1 / (k * n))) = 1
m = 1 / (1 - (1 - p ** (1 / k)) ** (1 / (k * n)))
```